# efficient way to calculate groups of points on a grid

Tags: r, spatial, combinatorics

Say I have an evenly spaced 6 x 6 grid of points:

```
width      <- 6
N          <- width^2
x_cent     <- rep(seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = width), times = width)
y_cent     <- rep(seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = width), each = width)
dat <- tibble::as_tibble(cbind(x_cent, y_cent)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(unit_id = rep(1:nrow(.)))
```

I want to calculate/ know all the possible ways to arrange 2 x 4 (e.g. length/width of 2 and 4) groups of points (accounting for a "residual" group of 4 points which does not need to be spatially grouped). Is there an efficient way to calculate or iterate over these groups in R? Note that these groups should not overlap with one another; they should all be spatially distinct.

I have tried to write an algorithm that creates a 2x4 or 4x2 (e.g. either horizontally or vertically placed) group at (0, 0) that then tries to fit the remaining points to groups, but I haven't been able to write enough rules to guide the algorithm to correctly group points together.

Comment: Maybe this is clearer to others, but I would appreciate some more explanation and examples. What does "arrange 2 x 4 groups of points" mean? what's a 2x4 vs 4x2 group? Are you referring to rectangle shapes with those widths and heights?

Comment: Thanks Jon, have updated the question, but yes you're exactly right that 2 x 4 refers to a rectangular group of points 2-points wide and 4-points long (or vice versa)

Comment: Should we assume the groups can't overlap? Should we assume in your example above that each acceptable arrangement has exactly four groups?

Comment: Thanks-- yes the groups should be distinct and not overlap. In the example above, you're right that there would always be four groups, with four residual points.

Comment: So, for example, this would be one acceptable grouping? (new row for each sequence) 111122
111122
333322
333322
-4444-
-4444-    Does the numbering of the group matter, ie do you care about permutations with the same groupings? What range of grid sizes are you working on, just 6x6 or generalized?

Comment: Yes exactly! the goal is to come up with function that returns something like this (and other viable combinations) as an output, and that could work on grids (and point groupings) of different sizes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243801/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-thomas-j-brailey).